# Request for the simplest jquery-ajax tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a bit new to ajax and trying to understand how it works with jQuery.

I am searching for an example for the **simplest tutorial** just to understand how to get started.

Let's say - that when the page loads I want that to ask for server (PHP) to insert inside body tag the words "Hello world"

How do I do that? (in the html and in the server side file)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at the jQuery documentation. The documentation for [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) provides an example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

that loads the content of `ajax/test.html` and displays it in an element with id `result`

We can then mimic it and call the `load` function inside the `ready` function that is executed after the page has loaded. We use the selector `body` to select the body element(s) and instruct the content of the(se) element(s) to be replace with the content of `ajax.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').load('ajax.php');
});
```

Comment: oh... so when do I use to .ajax function? I thought it should be somewhere in order  to make it an ajax...

Comment: ``.load`` is just an abstraction of the ``.ajax`` function. It does use ``.ajax`` inernally. ``.ajax`` allows you to specify more options and receive your data in a callback, instead of attaching it to an element. There are more aliases to ``.ajax`` that reduce it's complexity, like ``.get`` used in betamax' example.

Comment: You use the ajax function when you need more fine-grained control on what's going on. You'll get far with just the `load`-function. After that you might need to wander of to `$.get` and `$.post` to achieve more control. `$.ajax` is way past them. To tell you the truth, all of the functions load, get and post are there to make things easier and delegate to the ajax function eventually.

Answer (score 1):

OK in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<body>

    <div id="my_content">Nothing here yet</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>

        // When jQuery is ready
        $(function(){

            // Get the contents of my_page.php
            $.get("/my_page.php", function(data){

                // When the contents of my_page.php has been 'got' 
                // load it into the div with the ID 'my_content'
                $("#my_content").html(data);

            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `my_page.php` PHP file:

```
<?

    // This is what jQuery will get
    echo "Something is here now!";

?>
```

Comment: The `script` tags could be wrapped inside the `head` tags as there is no reason why they would be inside the body in the example. You also probably meant `#my_content` instead of `#id` as the selector. Furthermore, the question requested the selector to be `body`.

Comment: Yeah should have been `#my_content`, sorry about that. The script tags are in the body because of habit and best practices for performance. It means javascript is loaded last if it is at the bottom of the page - http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#body').load('ajax.php');
});
</script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
?>
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use the `body` tag instead of `<div id="body" />`. Using `body` as an id is a bit misleading and may cause bugs in either the javascript or the CSS.

Comment: `$.ready` will not work. I think you meant `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Aleski: It depends. In most actual project you will have alot of chrome around your actual content, eg header, navigation, footer. Using the body tag will also replace that chrome. You would not want that. Using body as an id will not create any bugs in css or javascript, however, I agree that it might be missleading to a human reader.

Comment: Bugs are caused by the human reader aren't they not? A poor web designer might spend minutes, or if pig-headed enough hours, finding why their stylesheets don't work when they use `body` all over the place.